# image buffer for video processing

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qthread

I want to develope an application with Qt and opencv , in order to process all the frames comming from a camera.
I have 2 Qthread, one for capturing image and the other for processing.
the processing thread is a little slow , so in order to process all the frames , I need to have a frame buffer.
I really have no idea how to simply impelement a frame buffer.
any help would be apprecieted.

Comment: Given that a single processing thread can't keep up with the capture rate you'll probably want multiple processing threads.  This looks like a classic candidate for a single-producer-multiple-consumer setup.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to create your threads to run asynchronously. When you capture the image, add it to a `std::queue` using the capture thread, and then let your processing thread pull from queue. Try to use pointers as much as you can for the images to cut down on memory use and processing time. Make sure you're thread safe and use `std::Mutex` when appropriate.

Since you are using QT, you could use [QQueue](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqueue.html) for the queue and [QMutex](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html) for the mutex.

Comment: may I ask you to write a simple code on the capture side and processing side? just to give me the idea to start.

Comment: If you supply some sample code, I'll take a look at it and try to help.

Answer (score 0):

if your processing thread is slower then the frame capturing period, meaning that your code will go out of memory eventually. You should consider decreasing capturing frame rate, dropping frames or maybe decreasing the frame resolution.

As for the buffer, go for a *thread safe <s>circular</s> queue* for frames, where, the capturing thread will be producer and processing thread will be the consumer. If the queue is full (it will be obviously) you have two options: *(1)* remove the oldest (but not being processed) one and add the new one. *(2)* Just drop the newest frame, which is pretty easy to implement.